# Drag and drop multiple files into javaFX

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm pretty new to Java. I'm building a samll app to help in my normal work, basically to process several files text files and add up the number of text symbols contained by those files. I would like to understand how to drop multiple files into a javaFX scene, since `handle(DragEvent event)` accepts only one file.

Comment: Why do you think a drag event can only accept one file?

Comment: Well, I haven't found any way to accept more than one with it. Would you be so kind to explain how to accept multiple files using it?

Comment: How are you even accepting one file? The only way I see to get file(s) at all is `event.getDragboard().getFiles()` (which returns a `List<File>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clearly accept multiple files in a `DragEvent`.
The following example displays the file names dropped to the scene:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Text text = new Text();
    StackPane root = new StackPane(text);

    root.setOnDragOver(evt -> {
        if (evt.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
            evt.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK);
        }
    });
    root.setOnDragDropped(evt -> {
        text.setText(evt.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::getAbsolutePath).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
        evt.setDropCompleted(true);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```