# Drag and drop multiple files in one by one manner into javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

**Requirement:** If user drop multiple files in one by one manner then how to consume it, I have code to get file(s), if user drop one or multiple files in a single drop.

I have found similar question here [Drag and drop multiple files into javaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920490/drag-and-drop-multiple-files-into-javafx) but answer is not what I am expecting.

Here is what I have tried so far to get dragged file in **Text Area** :

```
textArea.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            if (event.getDragboard().hasFiles()) 
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);

            event.consume();
        }
    });

textArea.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            List<File> files = (ArrayList<File>) db.getContent(DataFormat.FILES);

            if (files != null) {
                File file = files.get(0);

                // rest implementation after getting file

             }
             event.setDropCompleted(success);

            event.consume();
        }

    });
```

I can get a list of files using `List<File> files = (ArrayList<File>) db.getContent(DataFormat.FILES);`  if user drop multiple files.

But if user drop file one by one (more than one)then how to consume it (same as we find in gmail as shown below image)

.[image]

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with gmail. Could you describe the desired behaviour? For me this attempt seems illogical. The `dragDropped` event handler is invoked when the mouse is released. You however want to continue the drag&drop gesture that just has ended which would require the mouse button to be pressed...

Comment: What is 'consuming' in your case ? Because if you drop in once, you can directly act, but how to know when it's ended in you do one by one ?

Comment: I have updated code, added image of requirement. Gmail store files if user drop one by one. If `dragDropped` event can not perform as requirement, Could you please suggest me some other way to do it in javafx

Comment: You should replace `List<File> files = (ArrayList<File>) db.getContent(DataFormat.FILES);` with `List<File> files = db.getFiles();`. If you want to handle multiple drops, just keep a collection of all those files in your code, e.g. if you want to store all of them in a `ListView<File> listView` you could do `listView.getItems().addAll(files);` however you could also iterate through the files list and upload them to a server one by one, copy the files to temporary files to prevent the user from deleting them before you're done with them or whatever you like...

Comment: Thanks Fabian for your guidance. :)